# Which type of tabbar - navigation controller should I use with a storyboard?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I am attempting to connect a tabbar to a navigation controller.

I have the following 4 options (see image).

In the tutorial I'm following however, it says that two options will be shown only (viewControllers, and performSegewithIdentifier) so which one should I use?

[image: connection type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayrad, in your storyboard, since you want to use a navigation and a tab bar controller, the main controller must be the tab and then the navigation controller, so you will arrange you canvas in order to first have the TabBarController then the NavigationController connected to it, and then a view connected to both of them, this way you will have a view with both the tab and the navigation controller.